# App does not render fullscreen UI anymore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

iOS rookie here. I somehow messed up my layout and can't figure out how to fix it. My entire UI only renders in what looks like iPhone 4 screen size. The one thing that stands out to me is that I can't add constraints to my main view anymore.

Would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably deleted or don’t have the launch storyboard specified.  Go to settings and make sure the name matches your launch screen name.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!!